# When rotate a object to face to certain direction, the object will suddenly rotate a lot at certain direction(when almost vertical)

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6WwG.gif)

```
float3 zaxis = normalize(forward);
    float3 xaxis = normalize(cross(up, zaxis));
    float3 yaxis = cross(zaxis, xaxis);
    return float4x4(
        xaxis.x, xaxis.y, xaxis.z, 0,
        yaxis.x, yaxis.y, yaxis.z, 0,
        zaxis.x, zaxis.y, zaxis.z, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1
);
```

my code is above

Comment: I think it's caused by `normalize(cross(up, zaxis))`. If I understand it correctly up and zaxis become the same and the cross product turns into a null vector. You then normalize it meaning that at this singularity the xaxis flips strongly.

Comment: Is there any solution? I try to limit the direction not so vertically, but it did not improve.

Comment: You could try not normalizing, but I'm not too sure about the implications of that. Not really an expert on transformation matrices.